# Read and List all exports of an angular module

Tags: angular, npm

The initial situation is as follows: In the `node_moduls` folder of my project there is a module called `@example` with some components I want to use in the application. The amount of components varies therefore it´s necessary to state dynamically which components are included inside the module. The `example.module.ts` file looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FirstModule } from 'EXAMPLE_PATH';
import { SecondModule } from 'EXAMPLE_PATH';
import { ThirdModule } from 'EXAMPLE_PATH';
import { FourthModule } from 'EXAMPLE_PATH';


const MODULES = [
  FirstModule,
  SecondModule,
  ThirdModule,
  FourthModule 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...MODULES],
  exports: [NgbModule, ...MODULES],
  providers: [ExampleService]
})
export class ExampleModule {
}
```

The `MODULES` array contains all the components which are included. As usually the module gets imported into the app with following `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleModule } from '@example/example-module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ExampleModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
}
```

**Is it possible somehow to determine inside the app which components the `exampleModule` exports or rather the app imports from this module?**
So at the End in this example the app should know that `FirstModule`, `SecondModule`, `ThirdModule` and `FourthModule` are imported and could be used.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/W23YdaaW0hjHob1TN41k?p=preview

Comment: In your Plunkr you get the meta data from the the same module (`AppModule`). Is it possible to get the meta data of the imported modules like `BrowserModule`?

Comment: Just change the second parameter for `getOwnMetadata` method

Comment: `const annotations = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('annotations', BrowserModule);` leads to an error for me

Comment: One minute... let me fix it

Comment: Updated https://plnkr.co/edit/W23YdaaW0hjHob1TN41k?p=preview