# When and how s decorator applied to the decorated classes from the @angular packages

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator, reflect-metadata

If I use a decorator in my class the decorator is evaluated when importing the class. Here is the small example:

```
@NgModule({ ... })
export class BModule { ... }
```

Transpiled as:

```
var BModule = (function () {
    function BModule() {
    }
    BModule = __decorate([  <---------- decorators are applied here
        core_1.NgModule({...})
    ], BModule);
    return BModule;
}());
exports.BModule = BModule;
```

However, when the module or any other decorator is applied in the `@angular` bundles the output is the following:

```
var HttpClientModule = (function () {
    function HttpClientModule() {
    }
    return HttpClientModule;
}());
HttpClientModule.decorators = [
    { type: _angular_core.NgModule, args: [{ ... },] },
];
```

As you can see, the decorators are not applied here. They are just saved in the `decorators` property. Why is it different from my code?

The reason I'm asking is that when importing my decorated classes I expect it to have decorators applied and so using `Reflect` is possible:

```
const providers = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('annotations', BModule);
```

However, it doesn't work this way with decorated classes from the `@angular` packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When angulat resolves annotations it has [three options](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/core/src/reflection/reflection_capabilities.ts#L117-L137):

1) Direct API

```
// Prefer the direct API.
if ((<any>typeOrFunc).annotations && (<any>typeOrFunc).annotations !== parentCtor.annotations) {
  let annotations = (<any>typeOrFunc).annotations;
  if (typeof annotations === 'function' && annotations.annotations) {
    annotations = annotations.annotations;
  }
  return annotations;
}
```

We usually use this API when write code in ES5

```
MyComponent.annotations = [
  new ng.Component({...})
]
```

2) API of tsickle

```
// API of tsickle for lowering decorators to properties on the class.
if ((<any>typeOrFunc).decorators && (<any>typeOrFunc).decorators !== parentCtor.decorators) {
  return convertTsickleDecoratorIntoMetadata((<any>typeOrFunc).decorators);
}
```

This way angular reads annotations from `@angular/(core|material...)` libraries. Angular compiles libraries this way because it helps to optimize bundle. For example we do not need to ship decorator helpers like `_decorate, __metadata` and the code will be executed faster.

For that angular uses `tslib` when building library by running tsc with `--importHelpers` options https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/build.sh#L127.

Angular material does the same thing https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/tools/package-tools/rollup-helpers.ts#L9-L11

```
// Import tslib rather than having TypeScript output its helpers multiple times.
// See https://github.com/Microsoft/tslib
'tslib': 'tslib',
```

3) Using Reflect

```
// API for metadata created by invoking the decorators.
if (this._reflect && this._reflect.getOwnMetadata) {
  return this._reflect.getOwnMetadata('annotations', typeOrFunc);
}
```

This API is used when we use metadata emitted by typescript

To ensure you will get metadata correctly you can consider using function like:

```
declare let Reflect: any;
function getAnnotations(typeOrFunc: Type<any>): any[]|null {
  // Prefer the direct API.
  if ((<any>typeOrFunc).annotations) {
    let annotations = (<any>typeOrFunc).annotations;
    if (typeof annotations === 'function' && annotations.annotations) {
      annotations = annotations.annotations;
    }
    return annotations;
  }

  // API of tsickle for lowering decorators to properties on the class.
  if ((<any>typeOrFunc).decorators) {
    return convertTsickleDecoratorIntoMetadata((<any>typeOrFunc).decorators);
  }

  // API for metadata created by invoking the decorators.
  if (Reflect && Reflect.getOwnMetadata) {
    return Reflect.getOwnMetadata('annotations', typeOrFunc);
  }
  return null;
}

function convertTsickleDecoratorIntoMetadata(decoratorInvocations: any[]): any[] {
  if (!decoratorInvocations) {
    return [];
  }
  return decoratorInvocations.map(decoratorInvocation => {
    const decoratorType = decoratorInvocation.type;
    const annotationCls = decoratorType.annotationCls;
    const annotationArgs = decoratorInvocation.args ? decoratorInvocation.args : [];
    return new annotationCls(...annotationArgs);
  });
}


const annotations = getAnnotations(AppModule);
```

### Update:

**API for metadata created by invoking the decorators was changed in 5.0.0-beta.4**

```
const ANNOTATIONS = '__annotations__';

// API for metadata created by invoking the decorators.

if (typeOrFunc.hasOwnProperty(ANNOTATIONS)) {
   return (typeOrFunc as any)[ANNOTATIONS];
}
return null;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer) maybe add some links to the sources? also, it seems that we can rely on `decorators` being present until the `tsickle` is supported, correct? I showed the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45205562/2545680) that expects `decorators` property

Comment: and I think as soon as Reflect and Decorators are supported natively in a browser, the first two options will not be supported

Comment: Added links. I think we can use Reflect as fallback in this case

Comment: @Maximus In case when we don't know in which format library was builded. That's why angular uses all three options

Comment: unfortunately no, Reflect doesn't seem to retrieve metadata from `.decorators` property

Comment: No, when we have `.decorators` we use second options, when metadata was declared by using `__decorate([` we should use `Reflect.getOwnMetadata`

Comment: can you please show it in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/29XWrJd959gNrAzIM76N?p=preview)?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/W23YdaaW0hjHob1TN41k?p=preview See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881725/read-and-list-all-exports-of-an-angular-module